# QGIS Expression string builder has buggy text

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Whenever I open a tool which opens the familiar 'Expression String Builder' interface, the text in the input box behaves very strangely - the cursor is offset, and text becomes overlaid. This makes it very difficult to edit expressions using this editor.

Any suggestions on what settings could be responsible for this situation?

This screencap shows an example of the poorly rendered text, the string entered is:

`"SA22018_NAME"  +  '\n'  +  "2018_rollcount"`

[image]

Comment: Does it work using `||` instead of `+`?  The color of `'\n'` is unusual too... Is there any error message?

Answer (score 1):

From following the answers at [How do I change the font in the QGIS Script Editor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301891/how-do-i-change-the-font-in-the-qgis-script-editor) it seems this is a problem with my older version of QGIS 3.2.2 Bonn. It appears to have been fixed at https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20349

Another reason for me to get my organisation to update our QGIS version...

Comment: If your organisation doesn't let you update your own programs, push for them to switch to the latest **long-term release** (currently Version 3.4.8 LTR) This way you'll have fewer issues with buggy versions in the future.