# QGIS Desktop 3.2.3 - Font in Expression box illegible

Tags: qgis, expression, font

I have problems with the font in expression box and python console etc. The font is illegible and on top of each other. I have tried changing the font size and font but that doesn't seem to affect the font here. It only seems to occur on this one machine and does not occur on other machines with the same version.

[image]

Version: QGIS Desktop 3.2.3

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what operating system? what fonts do you have installed?

Comment: a few similar issues have been reported with older version, and it seems they have been fixed (like this [one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301891/how-do-i-change-the-font-in-the-qgis-script-editor?rq=1) and the linked [bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20349))